# Compare the current value with previous value in a loop in java

Tags: java, for-loop

How do I compare the current value with previous value in for loop in java and determine if they are different?

Here I have for loop that loop every time I click the mouse. Therefore `i` depends on where I click.

Here both the current `i` and the previous `i` are equal to 3.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/55dao9a9r8o4yis/Untitled%20picture%206.png

Here the current `i` equal to 7 and the previous `i` equal to 11.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/pj38l23ughn6ey9/Untitled%20picture%207.png

I am trying to make `if` statement to compare the two values of previous `i` with the current `i`.

Here is my for loop

```
public void mousePressed() {      
    if (state == 0) {            
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            if (mouseX >= cards[i].x && mouseX <= cards[i].x + cards[i].WIDTH && mouseY >= cards[i].y && mouseY <= cards[i].y + cards[i].HEIGHT) {
                cards[i].flip();                     
            }               
        }
```

Comment: You just need to store the old `i` in either a static or instance variable (depending on context) and compare to that on the next loop. If you show us the code you have currently for getting the `i`s then we can give an example

Comment: Can you post what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: When you say current and previuos `i` what do you mean because `for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)` will simply go through i=0-5

Comment: @ Richard Tingle. see the pictures they show you 2 cards and the value of i under the cards. The first value depends on which card you click on first and the second value depends on the second card you click on. I want to compare these 2 value if they are equal or not equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start "i" with "1", smth. like:

```
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        if (cards[i].equals(cards[i-1])) {
            cards[i].flip();                     
        }  
    }
```

Comment: this is not going to work because i is not increasing by one. The loop loops once every click and i could be an values from 0 to 6. i.e if i click on the first card i is 0 if i click on the fourth card i is 4 so it depends on where I click. My question is how do I keep track of the first i value and the second i value.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for

```
int currentValue=0;
    int lastValue=0;

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        currentValue =i;

        if(i>0){
            System.out.println(" Current Value is "+currentValue+" Last Value is "+lastValue);
        }   

        lastValue=currentValue;
    }
```

Comment: In your example i is increasing by 1. My for loop loops one every click and i will be different depends on where i click. e.g it could be 1 and 3. or 4 and 6 or any 2 values. So how do i keep track of the previous i.

Comment: This is pseudo code, you can modify this code as per your need. It's just a matter of how you manage last value in current iteration.

Comment: @user2944741 This confusion is caused by the mentioning of "The previous value of i", this is what I was trying to explain previously, I don't think you mean `i`

Answer (score 0):

```
 Map<String, String> previousRow = lines.next();
    while (lines.hasNext()) {
        Map<String, String> row = lines.next();

        if (previousRow.get(key).equals(row.get(key)))
        {
            System.out.println("Found Duplicate Product " + row);
        }
        previousRow = row;
```